# Opening all external links in Phongap's ChildBrowser using jQuery Mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile & Phonegap, and have the following code to open all external links in a certain div with the ChildBrowser:

```
$('.someDIV a').live('click', function() { 
    var thisUrl = $(this).attr('href'); 
    PhoneGap.exec("ChildBrowserCommand.showWebPage", thisUrl); 
    return false; 
});
```

For some reason, while the page loads in the childbrowser, it also loads in the background, as if there's no "return false".

I've found a workaround by giving the link's href attribute a value of "#", and using the title for the url like this:  And updating the jQuery code accordingly, but this is a problem where my links are dynamically generated, and I can't have the url in the title attribute.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to stop it from propagating too:

<del>.live</del>

```
.bind('click', function(e) { 
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
...
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

[edit]

The above had no chance of working. I copied the first line... Sorry

You have to use .bind to be able to override the default link action.

I don't use `.live()` in general and I suggest not using it if there's a way to do the same with bind. `.live()` is a bit magic and it sometimes has consequences.

Comment: Doesn't seem to wrok. event.preventDefault() didn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Edited. Don't use `.live` where you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks man. Using `.bind()` doesn't seem to work at all. Even an `alert();` doesn't fire when I'm using it (it does when using `live()`...

Comment: That's because you have to bind to existing elements. live works on everything, because it binds to the whole document and catches all events and filters them. bind works on a dom element, so you have to run this line when there already are `a` elements you want to bind to. It's in jQuery docs.

Comment: Well, like I said, my links are dynamically generated... That's the problem :)

Comment: So just bind it AFTER they are generated. If they are appended multiple times - unbind and then bind back every time. That's how everybody did that before jQuery had .live method. And everybody knew what's happening to their DOM. When abusing .live method people don't care about it anymore