# How to create pop up window using jquery ui dialog

Tags: php, jquery-ui, popup, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a link in my page A which will bring user to page B. I want page B to pop up without affecting my page A, using jquery ui dialog like how window.open() function does (eg:  `<a href="" onclick="window.open('abc.php','', 'width=100, height=100, location=no, menubar=no, status=no,toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no'); return false">  ABC </a>`
I have this in page A:

```
<a href="abc.php">link to page B  </a>
```

I have this in page B:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        //$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
        $( "dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            height: 500,
            width: 740,
            modal: true
            });
    });
    </script>
<div id="dialog">
//code for form of page B

</div>
```

My problem is that the content is displayed inside the dialog box but it's not pop up window. The dialog just display on browser's window as dialog box. Basically, page A is replaced by page B. but i want page B to pop up when user click a link on page A.
Anyone know how to do? Thank a lot.

Comment: call only a `DIV` as pop up not the whole page B.

Comment: Do you use Phonegap? If so you can use Childbrowser phonegap plugin to achieve that feature, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101665/opening-all-external-links-in-phongaps-childbrowser-using-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a javascript function on pageA as below

```
function showUrlInDialog(url){
  var tag = $("<div></div>");
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
      tag.html(data).dialog({modal: true}).dialog('open');
    }
  });
}
```

Second way to load your page into iframe

```
function showUrlInDialog(url){
  var tag = $("<div></div>");
  tag.html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + url + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>').dialog({modal: true}).dialog('open');
  
}
```

Now call this function on your anchor tag as below

```
<a href="#" onclick="showUrlInDialog('abc.php'); return false;">link to page B</a>
```

On page B only keep your form or html code

```
<div>
//code for form of page B

</div>
```

Comment: thx a lot. It works but I have this problem. After submitting the form, it should reload the page B. But page B doesn't re-load within the popup window but show in new normal window. How to make page B to be in pop up window even after reloading? Thank a lot.

Comment: see edited my answer to resolve your problem.you need to load pageB into iframe.